# Google Oauth2.0 connection to an account

Tags: google-oauth

I followed an instruction by the link (from google support manager)

https://support.google.com/business/thread/1904726/client-is-unauthorized-to-retrieve-access-tokens-using-this-method-service-account?hl=en

I canceled a connection between oauth and my account.

Now I have no idea, how to return it.

As a result I got an error - google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.',

What was tried next:
I created new project. And new customer id and secret key.

Then: oauth2l fetch --credentials credentials.json --scope adwords

Many thanks in advance for your help.